# Uses of Ground and floor

Tags: grammar, word-difference

When she entered her room she saw a snake crawling on the floor

When she entered her room she saw a snake crawling on the ground

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Usually

> **ground**

refers to an outside area of foundation dirt, whereas

> **floor**

is an inside area usually with a layer of construction above the foundation dirt.

The correct choice is

> When she entered her room she saw a snake crawling on the floor.

or

> When she entered her room *(through the window)* she saw a snake crawling on the ground *(outside)*.